# Swap results of a value from last years value in same month if the month-year combination is not equal to month-year of system

Tags: r, dplyr

I've a table as under

```
+----+-------+---------+
| ID | VALUE |  DATE   |
+----+-------+---------+
|  1 |    10 | 2019-09 |
|  1 |    12 | 2018-09 |
|  2 |    13 | 2019-10 |
|  2 |    14 | 2018-10 |
|  3 |    67 | 2019-01 |
|  3 |    78 | 2018-01 |
+----+-------+---------+
```

I want to be able to swap the VALUE column for all ID's where the DATE != year-month of system date
and If the DATE == year-month of system date then just keep this years value

the resulting table I need is as under

```
+----+-------+---------+
| ID | VALUE |  DATE   |
+----+-------+---------+
|  1 |    12 | 2019-09 |
|  2 |    13 | 2019-10 |
|  3 |    78 | 2019-01 |
+----+-------+---------+
```

Comment: This is unclear to me. You want the current month's row, and rows from other months if they're from a different year, but with them showing this year's year? Why would you want that?

Comment: I agree with JonSpring; this is not clear at all. Let's say that `2019-10` is your system date. Can you explain the rules for `ID=1`?  *Neither* `DATE`s coincide with your system date. Then why do you swap `VALUE`s? And why select this particular combination of `VALUE` and `DATE`?

Comment: if the date doesnt coincide with system date then I would want to swap the VALUES, if it does then keep the same row for the group of that ID

Answer (score 0):

As Jon and Maurits noticed, your example is unclear: you give no line with what is a wrong format to you, and you mention "current year" but do not describe the expected output for the next year for instance.

Here is an attempt of code to actually answer your question:

```
library(dplyr)

x = read.table(text = "
 ID  VALUE   DATE   
  1     10  2019-09 
  1     12  2018-09 
  1     12  2018-09-04 
  1     12  2018-99 
  2     13  2019-10 
  2     14  2018-10 
  3     67  2019-01 
  3     78  2018-01 
", header=T) 


x %>% 
  mutate(DATE = paste0(DATE, "-01") %>% as.Date("%Y-%m-%d")) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(DATE==max(DATE, na.rm=T))
```

I inserted two lines with a "wrong" format (according to me) and treated "current year" as the maximum year you could find in the column for each ID.

This may be wrong assertions, but I'd need more information to better answer this.